# Dealing with "convert to object" in a MemberExpression

Tags: c#, reflection, linq-expressions

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to do this:

```
var memberExpressions = ConvertToMemberExpressions<MyClass>(o => o.Id, o => o.Name);

...

public static List<MemberExpression> ConvertToMemberExpressions<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] methodExpressions)
{
    var results = new List<MemberExpression>();
    foreach(var methodExpression in methodExpressions)
    {
        var memberExpression = methodExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        results.Add(memberExpression);
    }
    return results;
}
```

The problem is that because of `Func<T, object>` (to be able to include both `int` and `string` as parameters) my methodExpression looks like this: `{o => Convert(o.Id, Object)}`, which is not what I need. I need to reach `o.Id`.

This does not happen with strings: `{o => o.Name}`, no conversion here.

I use `Func<T,object>` to be able to take advantage of Intellisense and reach the props of MyClass. I have tried using `Func<T, dynamic>` instead, but the result is the same.

It could be solved using multiple overloads:

```
public static ConvertToMemberExpressions<TClass, T1>(Expression<Func<TClass,T1>>[] methodExpression1)
public static ConvertToMemberExpressions<TClass, T1, T2>(Expression<Func<TClass,T1>>[] methodExpression1, Expression<Func<TClass,T2>>[] methodExpression2)
...
```

...but it is a sacrifice I would like to avoid if possible.

---

**The question**:

Is it possible to build `o => o.Id` from `o => Convert(o.Id, Object)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check whether your `methodExpression.Body` is a `UnaryExpression` with a `NodeType` of `Convert`:

```
public static List<MemberExpression> ConvertToMemberExpressions<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] methodExpressions)
{
    var results = new List<MemberExpression>();
    foreach (var methodExpression in methodExpressions)
    {
        var expr = methodExpression.Body;
        if (expr is UnaryExpression unaryExpression && unaryExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            expr = unaryExpression.Operand;
        }

        if (expr is MemberExpression memberExpression)
        {
            results.Add(memberExpression);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unexpected expression type {expr.NodeType}");
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

When working with expressions, the debugger is your friend:

[image: Image of the Watch window on expr, showing the type and the values for NodeType and Operand]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be the correct solution. I was probably overthinking this... `unaryExpression.Operand` was in front of my eyes all the time, but I thought I couldn't use it as a MemberExpression, go figure. Thanks again.